# TastyPie Resource include Set Items

Tags: django, tastypie

I was wondering what is the best way to include objects from another model that are related on a foreignkey?

Example:

```
class First(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Second(models.Model):
      first = models.ForeignKey(First)
      second = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

How would I create a resource for the first model that includes all the related objects in the second one? - I know how to do it for foreignkeys in the first one, but not sure about how to go about this.

Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score -1):

Put this on the resource that wants reverse relation

```
anyfieldnameyouwant = fields.ToManyfield(FooResource, 'relatedname', full = True)
```

In this case:

```
class FirstResource(ModelResource):

    second = fields.ToManyField(SecondResource, 'second_set', full = True)
```